# Tournament and cycles-reference request

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

I am looking for any reference on the subject of tournaments (simple directed graphs with a unique oriented edge between any two vertices) and cycles. More specifically, given a function $w:E\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ such that for any vertex $v\in V$:

$$ \sum\limits_{(v,u)\in E} w\big( v,u  \big)-\sum\limits_{(u,v)\in E} w\big( u,v  \big)=0 $$

i.e, such that the "out-degree" and "in-degree" is according to weight function and not just the amount of edges "exiting" $v$.

---

I am wondering whether there is a "classic" result about whether conditions under which one can extend an edge to a cycle. Specifically the edge for which $w$ is maximal.

Comment: Do you have a specific question about these weighted-regular tournaments and cycles?

Comment: I'm having trouble finding reference on the matter. I am wondering whether there is a "classic" result about whether conditions under which one can extend an edge to a cycle.  Specifically the edge for which $w$ is maximal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These sort of weighted tournaments (especially with the extra Eulerian-like condition) are not very commonly studied, but fortunately, cycles in tournaments are easy to find. I'll say what we can say in increasing order of specificity.

---

In general, for any directed graph, we can partition the vertices into [strongly connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component): a vertex set $S$ is a strongly connected component when for any $v,w \in S$ there are directed paths in both directions between $v$ and $w$, and $S$ cannot be made larger and keep this property.

We can replace each strongly connected component by a single vertex to get a graph called the *condensation* of the original graph. This is always a directed acyclic graph. In particular, if you're looking for cycles in directed graphs, these will always be found within a single strongly connected component and never between two such components. In particular, edges that go from one strongly connected component to another can never be extended to a cycle.

However, within a strongly connected component, every edge $vw$ can be extended to a cycle, because there must be a directed path from $w$ to $v$.

---

We haven't used the condition about sums of edge weights so far. We didn't need it to find cycles, but we can use it to make some observations about strongly connected components.

I mentioned that the condensation of a directed graph is acyclic. In particular, it has a source. That source corresponds to a strongly connected component $S$ such that all edges between $S$ and the rest of the graph are oriented away from $S$.

Consider the sum
$$
   \sum_{v \in S} \left(\sum_{u : vu \in E} w(v,u) - \sum_{u : uv \in E} w(u,v)\right).
$$
On the one hand, by the weight condition, the sum is $0$. On the other hand, every edge $uv$ with $u,v \in S$ contributes its weight twice, once with a $+$ sign and once with a $-$ sign, and so they cancel. We are left with only edges with just one endpoint in $S$, and we know all such edges are pointed away from $S$, telling us that
$$
    \sum_{v \in S} \sum_{u \notin S} w(v,u) = 0.
$$
All weights are nonnegative, and so we conclude that all weights on the edges out of $S$ are $0$.

This means we can delete $S$ from the tournament and keep the weight condition true for all remaining vertices. By repeating this argument, we conclude that **all edges between two different strongly connected components have weight $0$**.

Putting this together with our previous work, we can make some conclusions:

- Every edge with positive weight can be extended to a cycle. (It's possible that some of the edges with weight $0$ can be extended as well, just not the ones that go between two strongly connected components.)
- In particular, an edge with the maximum weight can be extended to a cycle, except in the case where *all* edges have weight $0$ (then, weights tell us nothing).

Actually, all of the above holds for directed graphs and not just tournaments. Since we can delete all edges with weight $0$ without breaking the weight condition, we get the following statement for free:

- Each edge with positive weight can be extended to a cycle in which all edge weights are positive.

(This has algorithmic applications: to find the cycle, we can do a depth-first search that only considers edges of positive weight, which helps us because it means we're guaranteed to stay in the same strongly connected component.)

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer. I fail to understand why you can claim  that for $v,u\in S$ the edge $uv$ contributes both negative and positive contribution. Are you instead looking at the complete di-graph? This seems to imply that you are including both a directed arc and it's "inverse".

Comment: Suppose we have the directed edge $xy$ and $x,y\in S$. Then when we take $v=x$ in the outside sum, we can take $u=y$ in the *first* inside sum, and get a $w(x,y)$ term. But when we take $v=y$ in the outside sum, we can take $u=x$ in the *second* inside sum, and get a $-w(x,y)$ term. These cancel, with no assumptions on the graph.

Comment: Just to be sure, all these results are true for any directed graph with such a weight function? It's just that this is much stronger than I expected.

Comment: Yes, any directed graph will work. More is true: we can use the weight function to decompose any such directed graph into a "sum" of weighted cycles. I can elaborate on that if it seems useful.

Comment: It does seem useful, but I think this will asking too much of your time. Thank you anyway.